# Sum cases that meet multiple criteria (pandas)

Tags: sql, pandas, group-by

I need to find the sum of cases in col2 where for each set in col1 (ABC), the col2 value has a Y in col3 100% of the time. In this case, B1 &
D1 meet this criteria, so N=2. Support in pandas or SQL are helpful (both are ideal).

```
| col1 |  col2 |  col3 |  col4 |  col5 |
|------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|  A   |   A1  |    N  |  1    |  256  |
|  A   |   B1  |    Y  |  2    |  3    |
|  A   |   C1  |    N  |  3    |  323  |
|  B   |   F1  |    N  |  1    |  89   |
|  B   |   B1  |    Y  |  2    |  256  |
|  C   |   D1  |    Y  |  1    |  3    |
|  D   |   A1  |    N  |  1    |  32   |
|  D   |   C1  |    Y  |  2    |  893  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this in python pandas

```
df.groupby('col2').col3.apply(lambda x : sum(x=='Y')==x.count()).sum()
Out[568]: 2
```

More detail :

```
df.groupby('col2').col3.apply(lambda x : sum(x=='Y')==x.count())
Out[569]: 
col2
A1    False
B1     True
C1    False
D1     True
F1    False
Name: col3, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what `col1` has to do with this.  You can do this with a SQL query:

```
select count(*)
from (select col2
      from t
      where min(col3) = max(col3) and min(col3) = 'Y'
     ) t;
```